# three rows layout content 100% height with sticky footer

Tags: html, css

Can anyone out there create a three row layout with a sticky footer. The content must fill right up to the footer but if the content is bigger than the page then the footer gets pushed down

Can someone create this or does anyone know of a tutorial that shows you how to do this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    html, body
    {
        min-height:100%; height:100%; margin:0px; width:100%
    }
    body > #wrapper
    {
        margin-bottom:-240px; height:100%
    }
    header
    {
        display:block; background-color:#ffd800; height:130px;
    }
    body > #wrapper > section
    {
        display:block; background-color:#ff6a00; height:100%; margin-bottom:-240px
    }
    footer
    {
        display:block; background-color:#ffd800; height:240px
    }
</style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <section>
        <header>
            Header
        </header>

        <div id="body">
            <nav>
                Left Sidebar
            </nav>
            <article>
                <p>Content</p>            
                <p>Content</p>            
                <p>Content</p>            
                <p>Content</p>            
                <p>Content</p>            
                <p>Content</p>            
                <p>Content</p>            
                <p>Content</p>            
                <p>Content</p>            
                <p>Content</p>            
                <p>Content</p>            
                <p>Content</p>            
                <p>Content</p>            
                <p>Content</p>            
                <p>Content</p>            
                <p>Content</p>            
                <p>Content</p>            
                <p>Content</p>            
            </article>
            <aside>
                <p>Right Side Bar</p>
            </aside>
         </div>
    </section>
    </div>

    <footer>
        Footer
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Man...there's got to be a SO to Fiddle way instead of seeing this ...anyways this is what you mainly need to get this working:

```
html,body{height:100%;}
.wrapper{height:100% overflow: hidden;}
```

I change some of the code (mainly cause I hate ids and needed to simplify...)

[**FIDDLE ME THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/jM4R6/2/)

Comment: The flaw with this is that there will always be a scrollbar with some scroll distance left even thought there is more than enough space within the content area to display the content without any scrolling.

Comment: well not necessarily ...you can always play with the percentages: http://jsfiddle.net/jM4R6/4/ but yes I agree with you there are more ways to do this

Answer (score 0):

This is the widely used sticky footer. Test it out in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkasarora/fmqkm/) I have created.

Simply populate the container div with `<h1>Hello</h1>` etc for testing, and see the footer sticked to bottom no matter how much the content is.